# Asymmetry definitions electric $\chi_e$ and magnetic susceptibility $\chi_m$

Tags: electromagnetism

Could anybody explain the asymmetry in the definitions of the electric susceptibility $\chi_e$ and the magnetic susceptibility $\chi_m$:
$$D=\epsilon_0 E+P\qquad\qquad P=\epsilon_0\chi_e E$$
$$B=\mu_0 H+\mu_0 M\qquad\qquad M=\chi_m H$$
The following definition would make more sense to me: 
$$D=\epsilon_0 E+P\qquad\qquad P=\epsilon_0\chi_e E$$
$$B=\mu_0 H+M\qquad\qquad M=\color{red}{\mu_0}\chi_m H$$
**Edit:** The electric and magnetic parts appear in the Maxwell equations in a very similar way:
$$\nabla\times E+\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=0$$
$$\nabla\times H-\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}=j$$
$$\nabla\cdot D=\rho$$
$$\nabla\cdot B=0$$

Comment: "making sense" is not one of the best-known features of this part of electrodynamics, frankly.

Answer (score 1):

It's ultimately a matter of definition but note there is an asymmetry in how the defining factors $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ occur.
From Gauss's law 
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S =\frac{q_{encl}}{\epsilon_0}\qquad \qquad \vec\nabla \cdot \vec E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$ 
with $\epsilon_0$ entering in the denominator.  From Ampere's law
$$
\oint \vec B\cdot d\vec \ell = \mu_0 I_{encl}\qquad \qquad \vec\nabla\times \vec B=\mu_0\vec J
$$
with $\mu_0$ now appearing in the numerator.  As a result the fields $\vec B$ and $\vec E$ which are defined by "elementary" integral laws are related to $\vec H$ and $\vec D$ by multiplicative or dividing factors rather than by two multiplicative or two dividing factors.  Note that the magnetization $\vec M$ is defined in terms of the field $\vec H$ whereas the polarization $\vec P$ is in terms of the "fundamental field" $\vec E$.

Comment: Actually in the way the constitutive equations are written, the $\vec H$ is the "fundamental" field and $\vec B$ the constituent one.

Comment: Writing Ampere's and Faraday's law in terms of $E$ and $H$ seems therefore more natural to me, since both represent *field intensities*, whereas $D$ and $E$ represent *flux intensities*. In this way this asymmetry does not appear. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Diracology yes my use of "fundamental" is suspicious and your wording is more appropriate.  I need to edit this..

Comment: @Carucel presumably you mean $\vec D$ and $\vec B$.  It is in fact more "natural" to use $\vec D$ and $\vec B$ since the rhs then become source terms alone, without the permittivity factors and thus independent of the material.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, yes you are right, sorry for my typo. Hopefully my edit makes sense now.

Comment: @Carucel no worries.  It's kinda weird it's defined that way but then the electric and magnetic fields are not completely symmetric since $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec B=0$ always...Often times is comes down to history.